# Permission to control revisions without giving full content access in D6

Tags: 6, users

I want users belonging to my 'editor' role to be able to create/revert etc revisions. To do this, as far as I can tell, I have to check the 'administer nodes' option in admin/user/permissions

However this seems to give editors the ability to create any content type (seems to override the specific content type permissions). I want editors to be able to create only certain content type (under node/add).

Is there a way to enable the node revision setting but restrict the content types that can be created?

Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [Workbench module](https://drupal.org/project/workbench).

> Workbench provides overall improvements for managing content that
>   Drupal does not provide out of the box. Workbench gives us three
>   important solutions:

Comment: Workbench module is only for Drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for this I guess is trying [Revisioning module](https://drupal.org/project/revisioning)

> Revisioning is a module for the configuration of workflows to create,
>   moderate and publish content revisions.

on the other hand, for problem with restricting to only a certain content type, you should use [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to achieve that.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Comment: Post comments as a comments, not in an answer. Comment in answer is one of the reasons that can get answer deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Sohail, I tried the Content Access module, it gives more permission options for edit/delete etc but unfortunately not for 'Add' which is what I need. I had a read of the Revisioning module it seems v. complicated. Will try it out if dont receive a simpler solution.

Comment: Actually Content Access gives you the permission to "Create any "content type name" content", try to search better, you will find it

Comment: @Sohail are you sure? Or am I going blind. There is nothing under the "access control" tab for managing a particular content type. And not under the permissions as far as I can see. Cant find reference to this in the documentation either. Can you give me a clue as to where theis seting is please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, doing it everyday, first UNCHECK create any content type permission, then just try this: go to the "Node" section of your permission page, and look for the name of your content type, you will see permissions such as "Create", "Edit" and "Delete"

Comment: @Sohail, I do not have a 'create any content type' on the permissions page. I have unchecked the "create <myContentType> content" already. This is not part of the 'Content Access' module - this setting was there before I installed the module. This is the problem - drupal seems to ignore this setting and lets you create it even if it is unchecked. Hmm, are you on some version other than D6?

Comment: well it's been a while im working on D7, but still remember when I was doing it with the same module back in D6 version. take a look at this link, the last comment is exactly what I said: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22749/allow-people-to-administer-only-on-certain-content-type

Comment: @Sohail, The last comment says "'Edit own content' is different with 'edit content type'"? Not sure how this is relevant. But anyway, at the top of the page it refers to: "admin/people/permissions" this is a D7 url. Does not exist in D6. So this is a D7 question, I'm using D6. I guess the issue I am trying to address does not exist in D7.

Comment: the concept is still the same, the admin/people/permissions is D7 permission page, D6 has it too

Comment: D6 has a permission page (I refer to this in my question). This is not the issue. It does not have a 'create any content type'

Comment: well I just downloaded a drupal 6 with no extra modules, there is a "node module" section in your permission page (admin/user/permissions) that you can set permission to (Create "content type name" content) permission for your role. if you have an online version of your website, you can contact me with your credentials so I can fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Sohail, The thing is it seems that Create "content type name" content is broken in D6. Apparently many module just ignore this setting (https://drupal.org/node/957118). There are a few other suggestions in this page that I will try. Anyway, thanks for your help.